# Add commit from git repository to GitHub

Tags: git, github

I've change one of the files on my local repository and I've add changes and save commit in git.

Now I want to send these changes and commit to project in GitHub.

Repository in GitHub exist but now I can add all the changes and commits.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

```
//  add all your files
git add .

// commit all your changes
git commit -m "message"

// Make sure you have the latest code in case someone else has committed changes
git pull origin <branch name>

// Update github repository with your latest code
git push origin <branch name>
```

[image]

Comment: Your explanation is clear, but I suggest to remove the image that is not so clear in relation to the question!! ;-)

Comment: I found out that for some people its much easier to understand it with image. but thank you for the comment

Answer (score 0):

As first command type;

```
git add *
```

then, write a commit message as follow:

```
git commit -m 'here the message'
```

and at the end, push the commit of your local repository on the online repository:

```
git push origin master
```

Probably this last command is the only one you need. If errors occur you need to type the command: `git pull` and then  `git push`.